# Renders with colors on either side of screen

Tags: rendering

When rendering video, there is a bright, flickering, vertical line 1 pixel wide (well maybe wider) on the left and right side of the screen.

https://youtu.be/HwnINVi3aH4 (I suggest watching it half speed)

It happens whenever something bright is on the opposite side of the screen, as though the bright parts on the left of the screen are shown on the right and vice versa.

[image]

Here's a frame given a black background to be more visible. See how the white shape top-left is visible top-right for a small part of the screen? And the larger white shape bottom-right is visible bottom-left.

This has happened multiple times, using MPEG4 Lossless and Image Sequence rendering. What's the fix? I'm using Eevee.

Comment: are you applying any glow in the compositor?

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, it's been solved by an option in the Scene > Film settings. While it may be a bug, there is an existing solution already in place.

Comment: @susu Got it... thanks

Answer (score 4):

The issue was fixed by enabling 'Overscan' under the Scene Properties > Film tab. Keeping it on the default of 3% appears to be fine.

[image: Scene > Film > Overscan]

I have re-rendered multiple problematic scenes with overscan enabled, and they have all rendered correctly.